# How do I send responses to multiple clients after a condition is fulfilled?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, queue, python-multithreading

I’ve been stuck on a work project. The problem is to accept connections from various clients, store them on the server in some kind of queue or list, and then after some condition is fulfilled, send response to the queued clients in FIFO order.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import time

all_connections = []
all_address = []
all_msg= []

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 4424))
server_socket.listen(20)

wait_list, interface_list, device_list = ([] for i in range(3))

print ("getting order from client...")              #Wait for next request from client

while True:
    clientsocket, address = server_socket.accept()
    all_connections.append(clientsocket)
    all_address.append(address)
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    message_from_client = all_connections[0].recv(1024)
    print(message_from_client)###
    decode_msg= message_from_client.decode("utf-8")
    all_msg.append(decode_msg)

    if "success" in all_msg[0] and len(wait_list) != 0:
        print("Received request: %s" % decode_msg)
        new_decode_msg=all_msg[0].replace("success", "")
        if new_decode_msg not in wait_list:
            print("stored in wait list")
            wait_list.append(new_decode_msg)
            socket.send(b'stored')
        else:
            print("already stored")
            socket.send(b'already stored')
        wait_parts= wait_list[0].split(" ")
        if wait_parts[0] not in interface_list:
            print("Server is ready")
            response= wait_list[0] + " connect"
            all_connections[0].sendto(response.encode('utf-8'), all_address[0])             #Send reply back to client
            interface_list.append(wait_parts[0])
            device_list.append(wait_parts[0] + wait_parts[1])
            try:
                wait_list.pop(0)
                all_msg.pop(0)
                all_address.pop(0)
                all_connections.pop(0)
                print(all_msg)
                print(all_address)
            except:
                pass
            finally:
                time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("waiting for disconnection")
            all_connections[0].send(b'not disconnected')
            time.sleep(2)

    elif "failure" in decode_msg:
        new_decode_msg=decode_msg.replace("failure", "")
        parts=new_decode_msg.split(" ")
        if parts[0] in interface_list and (parts[0] + parts[1]) in device_list:
            print("Received request: %s" % decode_msg)
            print("disconnected successfully")
            all_connections[0].send(b'disconnect')      #Send reply back to client
            interface_list.remove(parts[0])
            device_list.remove(parts[0] + parts[1])
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            all_connections[0].send(b'not disconnected')
            time.sleep(2)
    else:
        wait_list.append(decode_msg.replace("success", ""))
        all_connections[0].send(b'not yet connected')
```

So the client file is also an infinite while loop.
the client file:

```
while True:
        if args.connect:
            server_socket.send(bytes(" success ".join([args.interface, args.device]), 'utf-8'))
            recived_response=server_socket.recv(1048)
            d_rec= recived_response.decode("utf-8")
            msg_array=d_rec.split(" ")
            if 'connect' in msg_array:
                connect(relayboards.get(devices[args.device][args.interface].get("board")) ,int(PORT))
                digital_command(args.device, args.interface, "connect")
                print("ready to connect...%s" % d_rec)
                print("~~CONNECTED~~")
                #server_socket.close()
                break
            else:
                continue
                #print("oops")

        elif args.disconnect:
            connect(relayboards.get(devices[args.device][args.interface].get("board")) ,int(PORT))
            server_socket.send(bytes(" failure ".join([args.interface, args.device]), 'utf-8'))
            if  server_socket.recv(30)== b'disconnect':
                digital_command(args.device, args.interface, "disconnect")
                print("~~DISCONNECTED~~")
                #server_socket.close()
                break
            else:
                print("the device was not connected at the first place")
                #server_socket.close()
                break
```

Any ideas on this??
Thanks

Comment: Why are you not able to do that? At the moment, your server accepts connections and then just leaves them open. Is it doing what you expect?

Comment: @user253751 I am new to socket programming. I need to store the conn and addr in a queue or a list so that once the condition is fullifled i can send response to that conn which was stored in the socket.

Comment: Okay, so do you know how to make a queue or a list in Python?

Comment: I do. The client seems  to send blank message after the end of the actual message. This blank message   `( b'')`  is messing up my queue.

Comment: is there a way to store the connection parameters i.e `conn, addr`, and access it later to send message to `addr` and close `conn` ?

Comment: Are you trying to store messages in the queue? Just store (conn, addr).

Comment: @MichaelButscher The connections from various clients to server must stay alive until the server sends the message _connect_. I tried adding  `(conn, addr)` to a list and then access it using the index. But somehow the messages are not delivered to required client.

Comment: @mathais So... what happened when you added (conn, addr) to a list and accessed it using the index?

Comment: @user253751 Please refer to the updated question. I've added the client file too.Instead of the server replying to the specific `(conn, addr)` from the queue/list, the server replies to the client which sent the request at that instance.

Comment: @mathais The server in the question still doesn't do *anything*. It accepts connections, then it just leaves them open, and does not send or receive anything ever.

Comment: @user253751 I had not added the method of putting the (conn, addr) in a list. I wanted to get to know the right way here. Nevertheless, Ihave add it now. Check the updated post.

Comment: So this code is completely different from your last code. Now you haven't said what the problem with this code is. I would *guess* that you want it to read from all connections, not just the first one?

Comment: @user253751 This code has the same problem. If you notice the `all_connection[0]` will be removed only when the messagge to be sent is _connect_. The condidtion is not fulfilled and the message to be sent is not _connect_ , 0th index is still not removed and hence the reply to correct client fails.

Comment: "This code has the same problem." - *what is* the problem? The computer is doing what you told it to, I assume, but what you told it to do is not what you want. I don't know what you want. I only know what you told it to do, and that there is a problem.